# How to disable the view of a page if user is signed in and redirect back to the page where the user was on?

Tags: php, redirect, phalcon

I don't want the user to be able to land on this page if the user is signed in and if they try to go to this page it should redirect the user back to the page he/she was originally in.

What I have:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    Tag::setTitle('Home');
    if($this->component->user->hasSession()){
        $this->view->disable();
        $this->response->redirect($this->request->getServer('HTTP_REFERER'));
    }else{
        parent::initialize();
    }       
}
```

But this gives me a redirect loop error. Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to save in users' session/cookie his current page, to become able to redirect to last visited page. You solution will fail when visiting page directly (w/o referer header), from other pages (prolly you dont like to throw user away your website) or immediately after logging in.

Also, I would recommend to return `response` instead of disabling view. In standard Phalcon configuration, once you return a response `object` it immediately goes to `send()` it, without producing views in your case.

Also, for bulletproofness I would dispatch to other action, if user has not yet visited other page but is signed in.